# How to program a list in prolog that has n number of elements

Tags: prolog

I'm trying to code a program in prolog, that returns true only if the list contains first of all only the letters {a,b,c} and it must have the exact same amount of a,b and c. Furthermore it must be in this order [a,b,c].
Example : [] is true, [a,a,b,b,c,c] is true and [a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c] is also true but [b,b,c,c,a,a] is false, [b] is false, [a,b] is false, [a,c] is false and [a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c] is also false.

Here is what I tried to do, but the problem is that for each iteration the first c isn't put in the end :

```
langage11([]).

langage11(L) :-
  langage11(L, []).

langage11([a, b, c | A], A).

langage11([a|A], B) :-
    langage11(A, C),
    C = [b, c|B].
```

I hope someone would be able to help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
abc_list(ABCs) :-
    length(ABCs, Len),
    % The length is a multiple of 3
    divmod(Len, 3, AmountOfEachChar, 0),
    % The character-specific lengths are each a third of the total length
    length(As, AmountOfEachChar),
    same_length(As, Bs),
    same_length(As, Cs),
    % Contents of the character lists
    maplist(=(a), As),
    maplist(=(b), Bs),
    maplist(=(c), Cs),
    % Join the 3 lists
    append([As, Bs, Cs], ABCs).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- findnsols(5, ABCs, abc_list(ABCs), Lst).
Lst = [[],[a,b,c],[a,a,b,b,c,c],[a,a,a,b,b,b,c,c,c],[a,a,a,a,b,b,b,b,c,c,c,c]]
```

Comment: Hello, thank you very much for your help, as I just started to learn Prolog  2 weeks ago, I'm having trouble with Prolog, it would be really nice if you could just answer my last question here when you have time: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70326629/need-help-programming-a-list-in-prolog-that-has-n-number-of-a-c-and-m-number