# Need help programming a list in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I need help coding a program in Prolog that returns true if a list has n number of [a, c] and m number of b. But it must be in this order: a,b,c if there are the letters a,b,c in the list. In the list, the numbers of a and c must be the same, and the number of b can be whatever. Example : [] is true, [b] is true, [a,b,c] is true, [a,c] is true, [a,b,b,b,b,c] is true, [a,a,b,c,c] is true. But [b,c] is false, [a,b] is false, [a,a,b,c] is false.

Here is what I tried to do, I have n numbers of a and m numbers of b, but I just need to have the list to end with n numbers of c (same amount as a) :

```
langageAB([b]).

langageAB([b | S]):-
    langageAB(S).

langage8([]).

langage8([a,b]).

langage8([a | S]):-
    langage8(S).

langage8([a |S]):-
    langageAB(S).
```

Comment: start from simpler tasks. 1. define the language which accepts any number of `b`s. 2. define the language which accepts any number of `a`s followed by any number of `c`s. 3. define the language which accepts any number of `a`s followed by the same number of `c`s. 4. next we can try thinking about combining 1. and 3.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More performant answer:

```
abc_list3(ABCs) :-
    length(ABCs, ABCsLen),
    MaxAsLen is ABCsLen div 2,
    between(0, MaxAsLen, AsLen),
    % Same length for as and cs
    length(As, AsLen),
    length(Cs, AsLen),
    BsLen is ABCsLen - (AsLen * 2),
    length(Bs, BsLen),
    % Length of As, Bs and Cs has already been defined
    append([As, Bs, Cs], ABCs),
    % Contents of the 3 segments
    maplist(=(a), As),
    maplist(=(b), Bs),
    maplist(=(c), Cs).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(findnsols(13, L, abc_list3(L), Ls)).
% 554 inferences, 0.000 CPU in 0.000 seconds (100% CPU, 1735654 Lips)
Ls = [[],[b],[b,b],[a,c],[b,b,b],[a,b,c],[b,b,b,b],[a,b,b,c],[a,a,c,c],[b,b,b,b,b],[a,b,b,b,c],[a,a,b,c,c],[b,b,b,b,b,b]]
```

Original, less performant answer:

```
abc_list2(ABCs) :-
    % Start at length 0, if ABCs is uninstantiated
    length(ABCs, _ABCsLen),
    append([As, Bs, Cs], ABCs),
    % Same length for as and cs
    length(As, AsLen),
    length(Cs, AsLen),
    % Contents of the 3 segments
    maplist(=(a), As),
    maplist(=(b), Bs),
    maplist(=(c), Cs).
```

Result in swi-prolog:

```
?- time(findnsols(13, L, abc_list2(L), Ls)).
% 982 inferences, 0.001 CPU in 0.001 seconds (100% CPU, 1957806 Lips)
Ls = [[], [b], [b, b], [a, c], [b, b, b], [a, b, c], [b, b, b, b], [a, b, b, c], [a, a, c, c], [b, b, b, b, b], [a, b, b, b, c], [a, a, b, c, c], [b, b, b, b, b, b]]
```

Performance comparison:

```
?- time(findnsols(5000, _, abc_list3(_), _)).
% 1,542,075 inferences, 0.125 CPU in 0.124 seconds (101% CPU, 12337474 Lips)

?- time(findnsols(5000, _, abc_list2(_), _)).
% 37,702,800 inferences, 4.226 CPU in 4.191 seconds (101% CPU, 8921614 Lips)
```